# ios Charts constraint issues

Tags: swift3, ios-charts

I am using [ios Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to create a Pie Chart. But I'm getting the chart like this. If I'm giving a fixed height to the view which contains the chart, I want the chart and legend to fit inside it. Is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position as per your requirement through below line

```
chartView.setExtraOffsets (left: -15.0, top: 10.0, right:-15.0, bottom: -30.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never had this problem with this library so I would check if this could actually be a problem with the bottom constraint, try changing the bottom constraint to -20.

Comment: Im giving a fixed height constraint.